# Using TSQLT FakeTable to test a table created by a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I am learning to write unit tests for work. I was advised to use TSQLT FakeTable to test some aspects of a table created by a stored procedure.

In other unit tests, we create a temp table for the stored procedure and then test the temp table. I'm not sure how to work the FakeTable into the test.

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'TestThing'; 
GO                                                 
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestThing.[test API_StoredProc to make sure parameters work] 
AS 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Actual;
    CREATE TABLE #Actual   ----Do I need to create the temp table and the Fake table? I thought I  might need to because I'm testing a table created by a stored procedure.
    ( 
        ISO_3166_Alpha2 NVARCHAR(5),
        ISO_3166_Alpha3 NVARCHAR(5),
        CountryName NVARCHAR(100),
        OfficialStateName NVARCHAR(300),
        sovereigny NVARCHAR(75),
        icon NVARCHAR(100)
    );
    INSERT #Actual
    (
        ISO_3166_Alpha2,
        ISO_3166_Alpha3,
        CountryName,
        OfficialStateName,
        sovereigny,
        icon
    )


    EXEC Marketing.API_StoredProc @Username = 'AnyValue',                              -- varchar(100)
                                                 @FundId = 0,                                 -- int
                                                 @IncludeSalesForceInvestorCountry = NULL,    -- bit
                                                 @IncludeRegisteredSalesJurisdictions = NULL, -- bit
                                                 @IncludeALLCountryForSSRS = NULL,            -- bit
                                                 @WHATIF = NULL,                              -- bit
                                                 @OUTPUT_DEBUG = NULL                         -- bit


   EXEC tsqlt.FakeTable @TableName = N'#Actual',        -- nvarchar(max)  -- How do I differentiate between the faketable and the temp table now? 
                        @SchemaName = N'',       -- nvarchar(max)
                        @Identity = NULL,        -- bit
                        @ComputedColumns = NULL, -- bit
                        @Defaults = NULL         -- bit

  INSERT INTO #Actual 
  (
        ISO_3166_Alpha2,
        ISO_3166_Alpha3,
        CountryName,
        OfficialStateName,
        sovereigny,
        icon
    )
    VALUES 
      ('AF', 'AFG', 'Afghanistan', 'The Islamic Republic of Afghanistan', 'UN MEMBER STATE', 'test')

SELECT * FROM #actual 

END;
GO
EXEC tSQLt.Run 'TestThing';
```

What I'm trying to do with the code above is basically just to get FakeTable working. I get an error: "FakeTable couold not resolve the object name #Actual"

What I ultimately want to test is the paramaters in the stored procedure. Only certain entries should be returned if, say, IncludeSalesForceInvestorCountry is set to 1. What should be returned may change over time, so that's why I was advised to use FakeTable.

Comment: As per the documentation, "FakeTable cannot be used with temporary tables (tables whose names begin with # or ##)." ref: [FakeTable](https://tsqlt.org/user-guide/isolating-dependencies/faketable/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your scenario, you don’t need to fake any temp tables, just fake the table that is referenced by Marketing.API_StoredProc and populate it with values that you expect to be returned, and some you don’t.  Add what you expect to see in an #expected table, call `Marketing.API_StoredProc` dumping the results into an #actual table and compare the results with tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable.

A good starting point might be to review how `tSQLT.FakeTable` works and a real world use case.

As you know, each unit test runs within its own transaction started and rolled back by the tSQLT framework.  When you call tSQLt.FakeTable within a unit test, it temporarily renames the specified table then creates an exactly named facsimile of that table.  The temporary copy allows NULL in every column, has no primary or foreign keys, identity column, check, default or unique constraints (although some of those can be included in the facsimile table depending on parameters passed to tSQLt.FakeTable).  For the duration of the test transaction, any object that references the name table will use the fake rather than the real table.  At the end of the test, tSQLt rolls back the transaction, the fake table is dropped and the original table returned to its former state (this all happens automatically).  You might ask, what is the point of that?

Imagine you have an [OrderDetail] table which has columns including OrderId and ProductId as the primary key, an OrderStatusId column plus a bunch of other NOT NULL columns.  The DDL for this table might look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetail]
(
  OrderDetailId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
, OrderId int NOT NULL
, ProductId int NOT NULL
, OrderStatusId int NOT NULL
, Quantity int NOT NULL
, CostPrice decimal(18,4) NOT NULL
, Discount decimal(6,4) NOT NULL
, DeliveryPreferenceId int NOT NULL
, PromisedDeliveryDate datetime NOT NULL
, DespatchDate datetime NULL
, ActualDeliveryDate datetime NULL
, DeliveryDelayReason varchar(500) NOT NULL
/* ... other NULL and NOT NULL columns */
, CONSTRAINT PK_OrderDetail PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OrderId, ProductId)
, CONSTRAINT AK_OrderDetail_AutoIncrementingId UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (OrderDetailId)
, CONSTRAINT FK_OrderDetail_Order FOREIGN KEY (OrderId) REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders] (OrderId)
, CONSTRAINT FK_OrderDetail_Product FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] (ProductId)
, CONSTRAINT FK_OrderDetail_OrderStatus FOREIGN KEY (OrderStatusId) REFERENCES [dbo].[OrderStatus] (OrderStatusId)
, CONSTRAINT FK_OrderDetail_DeliveryPreference FOREIGN KEY (DeliveryPreferenceId) REFERENCES [dbo].[DeliveryPreference] (DeliveryPreferenceId)
);
```

As you can see, this table has foreign key dependencies on the Orders, Product, DeliveryPreference and OrderStatus table.  Product may in turn have foreign keys that reference ProductType, BrandCategory, Supplier among others.  The Orders table has foreign key references to Customer, Address and SalesPerson among others.  All of the tables in this chain have numerous columns defined as NOT NULL and/or are constrained by CHECK and other constraints. Some of these tables themselves have more foreign keys.

Now imagine you want to write a stored procedure (OrderDetailStatusUpdate) whose job it is to update the order status for a single row on the OrderDetail table.  It has three input parameters @OrderId, @ProductId and @OrderStatusId.  Think about what you would need to do to set up a test for this procedure.  You would need to add at least two rows to the OrderDetail table including all the NOT NULL columns.  You would also need to add parent records to all the FK-referenced tables, and also to any tables above that in the hierarchy, ensuring that all your inserts comply with all the nullability and other constraints on those tables too.  By my count that is at least 11 tables that need to be populated, all for one simple test.  And even if you bite the bullet and do all that set-up, at some point in the future someone may (probably will) come along and add a new NOT NULL column to one of those tables or change a constraint that will cause your test to fail - and that failure actually has nothing to do with your test or the stored procedure you are testing.  One of the basic tenets of test-driven development is that a test should have only on reason to fail, I count dozens.

tSQLT.FakeTable to the rescue.

What is the minimum you actually need to do to in order to set up a test for that procedure?  You need two rows to the OrderDetail table (one that gets updated, one that doesn’t) and the only columns you actually “need” to consider are OrderId and ProductId (the identifying key) plus OrderStatusId - the column being updated.  The rest of the columns whilst important in the overall design, have no relevance to the object under test.  In your test for OrderDetailStatusUpdate, you would follow these steps:

- Call tSQLt.FakeTable ‘dbo.OrderDetail’
- Create an #expected table (with OrderId, ProductId and OrderStatusId
  columns) and populate it with the two rows you expect to end up with
  (one will have the expected OrderStatusId the other can be NULL)
- Add two rows to the now mocked OrderDetail table (OrderId and
  ProductId only)
- Call the procedure under test OrderDetailStatusUpdate passing the
  OrderID and ProductID for one of the rows inserted plus the
  OrderStatusId you are changing to.
- Use tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable to compare the #expected table with the
  OrderDetail table.  This assertion will only compare the columns on
  the #expected table, the other columns on OrderDetail will be ignored

Creating this test is really quick and the only reason it is ever likely to fail is because something pertinent to the code under test has changed in the underlying schema.  Changes to any other columns on the OrderDetail table or any of the parent/grand-parent tables will not cause this test to break.

So the reason for using tSQLt.FakeTable (or any other kind of mock object) is to provide really robust test isolation and simply test data preparation.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a detailed explanation

Comment: Any way to upvote this answer twice without creating another account? :)

Comment: Thank you, your comment is acknowledgement enough